# Consequences of only keeping arm64 as valid architecture?

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64

I am working with a project that has following architectures defined in its Build Settings

[image]

What are the consequences of removing everything besides `arm64` from this list? Will it benefit app size / performance in some way on newer devices? What older devices / ios versions will become unsupported? And finally do I need to keep `arm64e` version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question is for hardware forum, not programming (Stackoverflow). But I'd like to try:

> What are the consequences of removing everything besides arm64 from
>   this list?

You'll, most probably, won't be able to support the newer devices that runs new chips (ex. Apple's A12 chip).

You won't probably be able to archive or submit your build to the iTunesConnect. Or say if you pass that phase, the review team will probably reject your build. I think I've experienced that before.

> Will it benefit app size / performance in some way on newer devices?

I don't think so.

> What older devices / ios versions will become unsupported?

If we are talking about the devices or iOS versions you want to support for project, then it depends on you. Some companies tend to ditch iOS 8, 9, and keep their minimum support for iOS 10.

> And finally do I need to keep arm64e version?

Yes, keep your `Valid Architectures` as is (Your current Xcode's defaults). Otherwise, you might experience the stuff I mentioned in the first part of this answer.

Some useful links:

http://iossupportmatrix.com/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices